# program crashes when started via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I have this problem with a tool, that I launch from a terminal on a specific computer - as far as I can tell it's a binary executable. If I remotely connect via ssh (using the -Y option) to this computer and launch the tool it crashes immediately reporting a segmentation fault. When I launch it locally it works.

Since it is part of a toolkit (actually started by a TCL script, not by myself) I'm not even sure if it creates any UI elements. The TCL script generates a UI which works fine.

The computer where the tool runs, is running some older version of red hat, RHEL 5 I believe. My computer (the one I want to ssh-connect from) runs a very recent version of Ubuntu.

Of course what I would like is be able to run the tool remotely without segmentation fault. Perhaps it is caused by the discrepancy between versions of the systems (or of ssh)? **What could cause a program to crash only when launched via ssh?**

Answer (score 0):

does the program work, if you run it on the remote machine locally? 
try to run it with DISPLAY=:0 variable as prefix in your ssh session.

Comment: Do I just set the environment variable before entering the the ssd command? I just tried this but it didn't help. I'm not sure what you mean with "as prefix".

Comment: before the command:
ssh -Y host "DISPLAY=:0 command"

Comment: if I try this then I get `Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server
Xlib: No protocol specified

Application initialization failed: couldn't connect to display ":0"`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Harry's suggestion: Did you run "xhost +" on your local machine before you you ran

env DISPLAY=:0 yourapp

on the remote machine? Overall, using ssh -Y is more likely to work than ssh -X, but it is till worth it to try a plain setup where the X11 connection runs on an unencrypted side channel directly to DISPLAY :0.